# why is the base function called instead?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-functions, vtable

In the following [code](http://rextester.com/AIV38590):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    A() {
        cout << " A constructor \n";
        sum(2,4);
    }
    virtual int sum(int a, int b){
        cout << "Base sum \n";
        return a + b;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    B() : A() {
        cout << " B constructor \n";
    }

    int sum(int a, int b){
        cout << "Overloaded sum \n";
        return (a + b) * 10;
    }
};

int main(){
    A* a = new B();
    // a->sum(4,5);
}
```

Why is A's sum invoked even though I have marked it as virtual and overloaded it in B ? At runtime, with the help of vtable shouldn't B::sum() be invoked ?

Comment: "_overloaded_" no, you override it!

Comment: There is no overloading going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because by the time you call the method, `a` isn't an object of type `B` yet.

Avoid calling `virtual` methods from constructors: it will lead to unexpected results (unless of course you expect this exact behavior, in which case you'd be spot on).

> At runtime, with the help of vtable shouldn't B::sum() be invoked ?

Not really, because the object doesn't have the `vtable` of `B` at that point.

Comment: And for completeness, something similar applies to making such calls from destructors.

Comment: I'm curios to learn. What are the disadvantages (unexpected results) of calling virtual methods from constructors ? (other than calling virtual functions and expecting the derived function would be called instead)

Comment: @juanchopanza can you please elaborate on that ?

Comment: @brainydexter see this [Scott Meyers link](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html). Basically, by the time you get to the base class destructor the derived object doesn't really exist anymore.

Comment: aha yes! since derived objects are destroyed first and then the base object, thus there is no derived object there at the time.

Answer (score 0):

The base constructor is executed first when you instantiate a derived class. That means that while the base constructor is executing, the construction of the derived object is not finished yet.

Avoid these scenarios by limiting the action in the constructor to what it is intended: initialising the object.